# Display WP Author List for a category in Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the author name and post count beside the name for particular category. That's why i used,

```
<?php
$catauthors = array();
$my_cat_id=4;  // THAT IS MY CATEGORY ID
$allposts=get_posts("cat=$my_cat_id&showposts=-1");
if ($allposts) {
foreach($allposts as $authorpost) {
$catauthors[$authorpost->post_author]+=1;
}
arsort($catauthors); //sort array in reverse order by number of posts
foreach($catauthors as $key => $author_post_count) {
$curuser = get_userdata($key);

$author_post_url=get_author_posts_url($curuser->ID, $curuser->nicename);
echo '<p><a href="' . $author_post_url . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Posts by %s" ), $curuser->user_nicename ) . '" ' . '>'. $curuser->display_name . '</a> <span class="label label-success">' .$author_post_count .'</span></p>';
}
}
?>
```

It seems OK but there all the author list showing with wrong sorting way. There highest post author names showing first, **BUT i want to show the authors name in Alphabetical ORDER For that Category**.

SO please suggest me a way to change that code or give me another way to that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does this gives you some direction?

```
$args = array( 'orderby' => 'author', 'order'=> 'ASC', 'category' => 4 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Full reference for get_post() arguments here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Actually i want to query post author Name

Comment: 'author' - Order by author lets you sort by Author then order takes care of ASC or DESC. Have you tried my example?

Comment: ya.. it showed blank.. 
http://s5.postimg.org/tm4dyrl5z/freelancingcare_2014_07_12.jpg actually want to show the author name in that way but i want to show with Alphabetical order